# Posts Displaying In Wrong Order

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a file which should fetch the latest 3 blogs from our wordpress blog and post them on the homepage of our site in DESC order. What is happening though is the Oldest blog of the three is showing first followed by the newest then the second newest. The oldest one should be last to be displayed.

```
$sql="SELECT title, post_name, date, content, CONCAT(LEFT(image, LENGTH(image) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(image))),'-500x375.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(image, '.', -1)) AS image
FROM (
  SELECT    
  p.post_title AS title, 
  p.post_status AS 'status', 
  p.post_date_gmt AS date,
  p.post_content AS content,
  p.post_name AS post_name,
  (SELECT `guid` FROM w_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value) AS image
  FROM w_posts p, w_postmeta m
  WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND p.id = m.post_id
  AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 3
) TT";?>
<div class="col-xs-12"><hr><h2 class="title-most-off"><a href="https://www.example.com/blogs/">Latest Blog Posts</a></h2> </div>
<?php
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $title=$row['title'];
        $shortTitle = substr($title, 0, 100);
        $content=$row['content'];
        $preview = substr($content, 0, 175);
        $date=$row['date'];
        $name=$row['post_name'];
        $image=$row['image'];?>


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 post">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/blogs/<?php echo $name; ?>" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive fw" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
        <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="blog-post-title"><?php echo $shortTitle; ?></h4>
        </div>
        </a>



      </div>  
    <?php }

}?>
```

Not sure why the order is not correct, the same thing happenens when I run the query in phpmyadmin the order is the same even though the date of the first shown result is before the second and third shown results. So the result is 3rd-1st-2nd instead of 1st-2nd-3rd

Comment: Have you tried adding `ORDER BY date DESC` into outer query?

Comment: try something like this ORDER BY table_name.date DESC

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply- I have that in the query that I included in the code example.

Comment: I have changed that to  ORDER BY p.post_date_gmt  DESC and still have the same result

Comment: As the first comment here suggests, you have no order by clause in your main query. The only order by is in a subquery. That is unlikely to influence the sorting of the main query.

Comment: Hi, appreciate you looking at this i have tried a few ways to put the order by clause in the main query but cant seem to get it to work, most likley because i am putting it in the wrong place. Can someone tell me where it needs to go as i can not find any information about using order by when there are multiple sub queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the code was correct all along, there was an issue with the date on one of the individual posts that was causing the problem.

Thanks for the help everyone.